# How can I expose data in a Relational Database to the Semantic Web?

Tags: database, rdf

How can I expose the data in a relational database to the Semantic Web?

Should the data be transformed to an RDF serialization? Or are there ways to expose the relational data to the Semantic Web without transforming it?

If the data is to be transformed, must it be RDF? What is the best approach for transforming the relational data to an RDF database?

Answer (score 3):

The RDF model approach have same specifications on W3C. I found a specification about [R2RML](http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/). A project for accessing relational database as RDF is [d2rq](http://d2rq.org/).